# npm modules wont get installed

Tags: angularjs, angular, npm, npm-install

I was trying to install dependencies which resulted in this warning:

```
npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.12 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.12 requires a peer of @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
```

I then tried to manually install `@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2` so i used:

```
npm install -g @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2
```

Which also resulted in

```
npm WARN @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.6.6 but none was installed.
```

I then used

```
npm install -g rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6
npm install -g zone.js@^0.6.6
```

Which threw no warning. I then proceed to again install `@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2`, but it threw same warning as before, like those two modules weren't installed at all. Has anyone met similliar problem?

What is causing this? I am trying to wrap my mind about it but can't find a solution, is there a way how to fix it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: This might be helpful to you https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5746

Comment: Do you have `"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.2" in your package.json?

Comment: @varit05 yes , its there

Comment: try Installing `rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6`, `zone.js@^0.6.6` & '@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2' locally